# viewing rownames in a heatmap in R

Tags: r, heatmap

My aim is creating a heatmap with a continuous legend. I tried a few paths and ended up with pheatmap. Legend is great, names of columns are ok, but the names of the rows don't show. I'd also like plot as squares not rectagles. Any ideas?

Comment: Greetings! Please provide code of what you have done so far as well as supporting information like snapshots of your plot to see what the issue is. As it stands it is difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, this is all new to me. I looked up pheatmap and saw that by default it would have a continuous colour legend and clustering with the details along the axis. I removed the first column with participant ID, did a sqrt and just ran it in pheatmap where it didn't show the Y-axis data and the plot was rectangles instead of squares. library("pheatmap")
Book1 <- read_xlsx("~/R/R projects/heatmaps/Book1.xlsx")
Book1$ID <- as.character(Book1$ID)  # converting numeric ID into chr
dat1 <- data.matrix(Book1[,-1])
sqrt_dat1 <- sqrt(dat1[,-1])
pheatmap(sqrt_dat1)

Comment: It doesn't let me add the plot. It has the legend right next to the Y-axis and no ID's alng there. X-axis is fine.

Comment: Thanks. You should add all this to the question, not the comments. Add some pictures of what you have so its more clear as well.

Comment: Also I know you're new here so I'm trying to help...always add the `dput` of your data when asking questions here. For example you have your excel data saved as Book1. If you run `dput(Book1)` and paste the output into your question, more people will try to help. A recent example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74012516/how-do-i-make-a-conditional-composite-score-based-off-a-categorical-variable-in